# Laravel keeps receiving my Axios request body params as strings

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a form where I have:

- avatar (file)
- household_required (boolean)
- name (string)
- designations (array)

I am sending these to my Laravel endpoint using `FormData`, I have validations in place in my backend:

```
        request()->validate([
            'name' => 'bail|required|string',
            'avatar' => 'nullable|file|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
            'household_required' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'designations' => 'required|array',
            'designations.*' => 'required|string',
        ]);
```

I'm getting validation errors as follows:

```json
{
    "message": "The avatar field must be a file. (and 4 more errors)",
    "errors": {
        "avatar": [
            "The avatar field must be a file.",
            "The avatar field must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png."
        ],
        "household_required": [
            "The household required field must be true or false."
        ],
        "has_fees": [
            "The has fees field must be true or false."
        ],
        "designations": [
            "The designations field must be an array."
        ]
    }
}
```

When I log the request values, everything is casted into a string. So, they obviously fail each time.

I would be very happy if anyone has a solution to this problem?

I have tried adding `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to my Axios call, but I get an empty array with no values in it. I have scoured google to try to find some information about it but i'm not getting anywhere. I feel like i'm running circles at the moment, so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: show how you are sending the request

Comment: Show what you get in the request using dd() or dump() before validating.

Comment: Will do as soon as I get near my computer.

Comment: [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#value) is always sent as strings or `File`.  You need to parse the data on Laravel side before doing validation, e.g. with `json_decode`